# How can I hide item entries in foreign key forms when they have 0 quantity in django forms?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I want to hide the item entries that are 0 or doesn't have any in stock, my current code for the item borrowing process is. The class Item is where I store the stock in the warehouse and the Activity is where i store the borrowed orders.

***Models.py***

```
class Item(models.Model):

ItemName = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
Quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=1,
    validators=[ 
        MaxValueValidator(100),
        MinValueValidator(0)
    ])
ModelNum = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
Category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
is_draft = models.BooleanField(default=True)
reorder_level = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=10,
    validators=[
        MaxValueValidator(100),
        MinValueValidator(1)
    ])

class Meta: 
    verbose_name_plural = 'Item'

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.ItemName}'



class Activity(models.Model):

Item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
staff = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
project_site = models.ForeignKey(Projects, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
Quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, default=1,
    validators=[
        MaxValueValidator(100),
        MinValueValidator(1)
    ])
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
is_draft = models.BooleanField(default=True)
request_status = models.IntegerField(default=0,
    validators=[
        MaxValueValidator(3)
    ])
return_status = models.IntegerField(default=0,
    validators=[
        MaxValueValidator(3)
    ])
note = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True)


class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Item Request'

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.Item}'
```

***Forms.py***

```
class ActivityForm(forms.ModelForm): 

class Meta:
    model = Activity
    fields = ['Item', 'Quantity', 'project_site']
```

Comment: How do you know that the item does not have any stock? It seems like `Activity` is an "order" not the "stock".

Comment: Wait i forgot to post the item inventory model where i store my stocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit choices to `Item`s that have a `quantity` that is at least one with the [**`limit_choices_to=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to):

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(
        Item,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        limit_choices_to={'Quantity__gt': 0}
    )
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `item` instead of <s>`Item`</s>.